Guesstimate a multiple choice exam
Exam time is here and the final consists of 20 True/False questions. Unfortunately you are a very bad student and you only know the answer to 5 of the questions. It so happens that the answers to the 5 questions you know are all True. For the other 15 questions you have no clue and have to guess.
The teacher gave one hint for the exam: Exactly 14 of the questions are True and the other 6 are False. That is probably meant to help the good students who know the answer to 18 or 19 questions deduce the missing answers.
You are trying to maximize your expected score in the exam. The score is the number of correct answers, there is no penalty for wrong answers. Question: How many of your 15 guesses should be True and how many should be False?
Disclaimer: This is a fairly easy puzzle, just don't get tricked.

I'm guessing that the teacher will have to set the pass/fail threshold higher than 70% :-)

@Hilmar in our Math's true/false section of the test, a wrong answer would score (-1) rounded up to 0 if your total section score was negative. Thus, guessing everything true would be 14-6 = 8 < 10 points, resulting in a failing test score :)

@infinitezero I added another sentence saying the wrong answers occur no penalty. That was the grading intended for the puzzle. However, even if you receive -1 for each wrong answer, the strategy would still work out the same. You would just receive less points.

Unless I got tricked,

 All your 15 guesses should be True

because

 Let $T_g$ be the number of True guesses, and $F_g$ be the number of False guesses
 Then your expected score is $5 + \frac9{15} \times T_g + \frac6{15} \times F_g$
 Because we know $14 - 5 = 9$ of the remaining answers are True and $6$ are False
 Also, $T_g + F_g = 15$
 Simplifying, expected score = $11 + T_g / 5$
 So, to maximise the score, we always guess True


 giving, fyi: maximum expected score = $11 + 15 / 5 = 14$


@JulioDiEgidio Why would order matter? Assuming it's not one of the known questions, is question #1 more or less likely to be True than question #20?

@JulioDiEgidio I'd recommend thinking about it this way: let's say you pick a random question out of the remaining 15 - what is the probability that the answer is True? Now, let's say you pick another - does the probability change? No, it doesn't (because you don't actually know what the correct answer to the first question was - it's not a case of Bayes' theorem)

@JulioDiEgidio my answer agrees with your calculations! (except you're ignoring the 5 correct answers which is fine).
If you put (T_g, F_g) = (14, 1) and (13, 2) respectively, you'll find the value from my formula of expected score matches the probability weighted average of your values.

@JulioDiEgidio rot13(Qb lbh nterr gung gur rkcrpgrq fpber sbe 2 Snyfr, 13 Gehr vf 8.6 nppbeqvat gb lbhe pnyphyngvbaf? Jung vf gur rkcrpgrq fpber sbe 15 Gehr gura?)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Same result as @fandango96 but perhaps a simple more generic explanation.

 to maximize your expected score all you need to do is optimally guess the other questions you do not know the answer to


 in this particular case, the teacher allowed you to figure out: $9$ remaining answers are True and $6$ remaining answers are False

What matters is:

 ratio $\frac{3}{2} > 1$ i.e. more answers are True than answers are False

Then optimal is:

 to always guess True

because this way:

 probability ($\frac{3}{5}$ in this case) to guess correct per question is bigger than probability ($\frac{2}{5}$ in this case) to guess wrong per question


 each such guess has (equal) higher individual probability to be correct and expected score for all the remaining $15$ questions in this case is indeed $15 * \frac{3}{5} = 9$


 add $5$ (or for that matter any as long as teacher hint applies) number of answers you did not guess but knew to be correct and end up with maximum expected score $14$ equal to @fandango96 result

OP mentions tricky perhaps because:

 all one needs to focus on is teacher's hint which (happened to) reveal for you (and maybe others) which answer True or False to always select having higher probability to be correct


The trickyness I thought of was that a very bad student might be tempted to ensure exactly 14 True and 6 False answers which sounds logical but is not optimal.

@quarague : right, and I was initially tricked as well. Your puzzle is interesting in that it illustrates how multiple choice can potentially sometimes result in people knowing less to score higher, say, assuming more or less even distributed answers. Did you create puzzle yourself?


 Let the number of answers we know to be true be $t$. Then we know that $5-t$ answers are false. There are $14-t$ true and $t+1$ false answers are left.  Let's have $n$ true answers out of the $15$ questions we don't know how to answer. If we have $x_1$ true answers that are correct and $x_2$ that aren't, the number of false answers that should have been true is $14-t-x_1$. There are $6-(5-t)-x_2 = 1+t-x_2$ false but correct answers, so the total number of correct answers is $1+t+x_1-x_2$ and the number of possible combos is:  $C(x_1+x_2, x_1) * C(15-x_1-x_2, 1+t+x_1-x_2)$  If the latter is at its maximum, then:  $C(x_1+x_2, x_1) * C(15-x_1-x_2, 1+t+x_1-x_2) > C(x_1+x_2, x_1+1) * C(15-x_1-x_2, 3+t+x_1-x_2)$  $C(x_1+x_2, x_1) * C(15-x_1-x_2, 1+t+x_1-x_2) > C(x_1+x_2, x_1-1) * C(15-x_1-x_2, t+x_1-x_2-1)$  $[(x_1+1)/x_2] * (2+t+x_1-x_2)*(3+t+x_1-x_2)/[(14-2x_1-t)(13-2x_1-t)] > 1$  $[(x_2+1)/x_1] * (15-2x_1-t)(16-2x_1-t)/ [(1+t+x_1-x_2)*(t+x_1-x_2)] > 1$  $[(x_1 + x_2)*...*(x_2+1)/x_2!]*[(15-x_1-x_2)*...*(15-x_1-x_2)/(1+t+x_1-x_2)!]$  If you answer everything you don't know as true, you guarantee $14-t$ correct answers out of them. If we want $1+t+x_1-x_2$ to exceed $14-t$ at some points:  $1+t+x_1-x_2 > 14-t$  $t<=5$  $2t+x_1-x_2>13$  $x_1-x_2>=4$  $2*(1+t+x_1-x_2) > 15-x_1-x_2$ and $x_1+x_2 < 2x_1$, so the combination is less than the maximum.  We can just replace $x_1$ with $x_2$, and realize that both sides where $x_1>x_2$ and vice versa give the same number of combinations for a certain $x_1+x_2$, so $14-t$ can't be exceeded. You have to answer all the remaining questions as true.


Sorry to say. The number of answers we (and everybody) know(s) to be true is given by teacher: $14$. So $t = 14$. I am not sure I understand the remaining of your first sentence. Perhaps you confused me in terminology?

$t$= the answers we know are true. 14 answers should be true in total including them, so out of the remaining 15 questions we don't know the answer to, there must be $14-t$ ones for which the correct answer is true.

OK so $t = 5$ ? Then what about the $5 − t = 0$ false answers  in your first sentence? I guess I am still confused. That said: your combinatorial explanation looks acceptable but seems overly complex since all that matters is $9 > 6$ ... we should perhaps take my confused argumentation in separated chat thread :)

There's $5-t$ but no $5-t=0$. There's a difference between false and incorrect. False answers are just the ones that we answer as false. We know the answers to the first 5 questions, so they're all correct whether true or false.

Right, thanks for reply

As you know 5 ans are true, only 15 quetion ae left.
Now True left = 14-5 = 9 ,  False left = 6
Now you want to maximize your score, so leave it on GOD and randomly select any 9 quetion as True and rest 6 quetion as False.
So maximum possible marks can be 20
and minimum possible marks can be 8

It depends how you understand "maximum score". I understand it refers to the average score if you would run this strategy infinite times. Your strategy has a min score of 8 and a max score of 20, making an average score of 14 when ran infinite times, but you have a variance between 8 and 20.  By choosing all answers True you achieve a score of 14 with 0 variance.
